# GitLab and GitLab Runner 15.11 error: fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

After upgrading GitLab to `v15.11.12` and GitLab Runners to `v15.11.1`, I have started seeing the following error in some of the jobs which were working fine before: `fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output`.

What is the reason for this? Why am I seeing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following 2 solutions:

- Increase CPU and/or Memory request and limit for GitLab Runner containers (build, service, and/or helper).
- Set `GIT_DEPTH` in the GitLab CI job to `1`.